# How do I abort object instance creation in Python?

Tags: python, object

I want to set up a class that will abort during instance creation based on the value of the the argument passed to the class. I've tried a few things, one of them being raising an error in the `__new__` method:

```
class a():
    def __new__(cls, x):
        if x == True:
            return cls
        else:
            raise ValueError
```

This is what I was hoping would happen:

```
>>obj1 = a(True)
>>obj2 = a(False)
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
```

`obj1` exists but `obj2` doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't you override `__init__(self, ...)` instead?

Comment: @matt b. It's not as semantic if then intent is to stop object creation. It does work though.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Why would raising an exception in `__new__` be preferable to raising one in `__init__`. The result seems the same to me and `__init__` is where all the other initialization code goes. Why shouldn't this go there as well?

Comment: @Arlaharen. because it's not __initilization__ code. It's __conditional construction__ code. It seems like `__init__` should only throw an exception if it runs into trouble initializing the instance. Here, it's an explicit test that's being done. I'm probably just quibbling though. I would say that if you want to do it in the initializer, just try to use whatever `x` is and let that raise an exception or go through.

Comment: I really think that the advice one would want to give in general is to treat `__init__` as the constructor. If the construction of the object needs to be aborted, for any reason, it works just as well to raise an exception there. Overriding `__new__` is very rarely needed and for everyday normal classes I think it should be avoided. Doing so keeps the class implementation simple.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you override `__new__`, dont forget to call to super!

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __new__(cls, x):
...         if x:
...             return super(Test, cls).__new__(cls)
...         else:
...             raise ValueError
... 
>>> obj1 = Test(True)
>>> obj2 = Test(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __new__
ValueError
>>> obj1
<__main__.Test object at 0xb7738b2c>
>>> obj2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'obj2' is not defined
```

Simply returning the class does nothing when it was *your job* to create an instance. This is what the super class's `__new__` method does, so take advantage of it.

Comment: If I need x variable too, what should I do?

Answer (score 9):

Just raise an exception in the initializer:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        if not x:
            raise Exception()
```

Comment: `__init__` is not the constructor, it is the initializer. You're thinking of `__new__`