# Python: Deleting a class instance

Tags: python, class, del

I'm new to Python and try to code some extras in my lerning lessons so now i need to code a class that crates an cube and than two methods. The methods are not the problem, but i want to generate a fail-save when creating my cube.

When you create the cube with any other types than int or float it should return that thats invalid and delete the created instance. I googled, tried and can't figure out how to get it done.

I also would like to generate the instance name inside the fail-save text. So it says "[...]instance "a" will be deleted[...]" when i create:

```
a = Cube("not an int or float")
```

and: "[...]instance "b" will be deleted[...]" when i try to create:

```
b = Cube("not an int or float")
```

---

Code:

```
class Cube():
    def __init__(self, length):
        if type(length) == int or type(length) == float:
            self.length = length
        else:
            print("The type of length has to be int or float.\nThe instance (a) will be deleted!!")
            del self
        
    def surface(self):
        print("surface")
    
    def volume(self):
        print("volume")
        

# creating an instance of the cube-class 
a = Cube("not an int or float")

# and test the methods
a.surface()
a.volume()
```

Comment: Why not just raise an error? `raise TypeError('must be an int or float')`

Comment: Metaclasses will help doing this, but if you want language-agnostic approach then you can use a function to create the instance and check the arguments before creating the instance.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 Thanks for the fast answer, good idea but an error kills the code right? so when i learn afterwards the inputs and the person enters a string the program stops and he has to start all over again, than just entering an int or float in the next try.

Comment: @khachik so you mean like

`i_value = input_value
i_name = input_instance_name
if type(i) == int or type(i) == float:
            i_name = Cube (i_value)
        else:
            print("The type of length has to be int or float.\nThe instance " + i_name + " wasn't created!!")`

Comment: @DKay36 The user can catch the error if they want. You just need to document that `Cube` could raise an exception.

Comment: There's no need to use `del`, though; if `Cube` raises an exception, no assignment to `a` or `b` takes place, so the object will be subject to immediate garbage collection.

Comment: @chepner Okay thanks, so i maybe need to learn a little bit further to handle exceptions :)

Comment: You can search up [try-except blocks](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to learn how to capture exceptions and either ignore or handle them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I abort object instance creation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867718/how-do-i-abort-object-instance-creation-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply raise an exception if there is a problem with initialization. The exception will prevent the assignment from taking place, which means the object will be subject to immediate garbage collection, so you don't need to use `del` (which has no real effect anyway; `del` just decrements the reference count of the object by deleting the *name*, but the name `self` would go out of scope anyway, with the same effect).

Use `isinstance` to check the type of the parameter.

```
class Cube:
    def __init__(self, length):
        if not isinstance(length, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError("Length must be an int or a float")

        self.length = length

    ...
```

Ideally, though, you leave the burden to the caller to provide the correct type. You can use type hints to make it easier for the user to catch such errors:

```
from typing import Union


class Cube:
    def __init__(self, length: Union[int, float]):
        self.length = length

    ...
```

A tool like `mypy` can be used to check *statically* that no attempt to pass a different type of argument.